# move express js app from localhost to web server

Tags: mysql, node.js, apache, express, web-applications

I was developing a CRUD web app through the use of express js, node js and a local SQL database (MySQL) locally, but now it's time to move to the web and I chose an apache web server that supports MySQL.

I already have the database loaded on the Apache web server.

I have already modified the credentials for the connection to the web server (I know that they are correct because I am connected via MySQL local server to it via a tunnel), through something like that:

```
app.use(
connection(mysql,{

    host: '127.127.127.127',      //'web hostname'
    user: 'root',
    port: '80',
    password : 'password',
    database:'db_name'

},'pool') //or single

);
```

But when I'm going to query on it I get an error on the *connection.query()* command:

> ... throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
>           ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined ...

for example in this part of the code:

```
exports.view1 = function(req, res){

  req.getConnection(function(err,connection){

    var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM table',function(err,rows)
    {

        if(err){
          console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );
        }else{
          res.render('view',{page_title:"Table view",data:rows});
        }

     });

  });

};
```

1) I'm sure that this error is due to the fact that the connection variable is empty, so it is not possible to perform the query, every help is welcome.

2) I have not found much on the net, but is it possible to continue to use express js even on an Apache web server? Do I have to change something in the formulation of database queries?

**[SOLVED]** Maybe it can help someone in my same situation. I had to change servers online, going from a Mysql server to a node js, in order to already have the basic functionality of node for the management of my app. However I had to install the mysql-server package, but the connection to my app express js, once moved from local to the server, with the right credential changes, worked properly.

Comment: Check `err` in `getConnection` callback.

Comment: You wouldn't normally use apache to run a node applicaiton, or at least I have not.

When hosting my personal node apps I write, I use digital ocean or aws. See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @dostu tank you for the reply, how can I check it?

Comment: @RichardWilliamson thank you for the reply. I understand, it is not the best to use an Ubuntu server from a windows pc, but I have been forced to use it. I'm reading your guide, I hope you help me.
Why can MySQL easily connect and query, while a javascript web app is not?

Comment: Use a debugger or just print it out with `console.log(err)` in `getConnection` callback.

Comment: @dostu I tried printing the error on the video, oh received two different errors, the first *Error Selecting: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'admin' @ 'localhost' (using password: YES)* , I think because the credentials were wrong (I was using those of MySQL local access) while if I use the official web server ones I get this error: *Error Selecting: Error: Handshake inactivity timeout* .

Comment: @dostu I also tried to access another page of my web app, I do not know if it affects but I'm working with the web app in local (localhost: 3000) and trying to read from the database online, in this second page, gives me the same *Handshake inactivity timeout* error, but then part and I get the usual error in the above query.